# Moviepy Making a CompositeVideoClip of two concatenate_videoclips

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

Working with the Moviepy lib and I've been beating my head off a wall with this last step for a while.

```
GifClips = concatenate_videoclips(TheGIFs, method='compose')
TextClips = concatenate_videoclips(TheTexts, method='compose')
```

I've written both of these to separate files and they look fine. But I'm having a problem getting them to combine properly.

I'm trying:

```
FinishedClips = CompositeVideoClip([GifClips, TextClips], size=(1920,1080))
```

It has the audio from TextClips and shows the GifClips but the text isn't visible. It did show when written alone without the composite.

It *does* work if I combine GifClips with a single TextClip but this doesn't work when I need text clips to run one after another.

I could run a CompositeVideoClip with every single TextClip and a part of the GifClips and then concatenate them all together but that doesn't seem like the neatest way of doing this. My guess is there's a fairly obvious argument here somewhere but looking through the docs and examples I'm struggling so far.

Any suggestions on how I could get the TextClips clip to show up properly in a composite would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alright looks like I found the answer. Remove the method argument when concatenating the TextClips and set the position again once the concatenate is done.